# Client interactive web map

Tags: qgis, qgis-web-client

i am new to gi’s and i have been using your app for a couple of weeks. I want to ask how i can make a webmap were the client can add points and details about them. I have used the qgis2web plugin however there is no client interaction over there.

Does the qwc2 have this feature?

In other words, how can i make a webmap with qgis, where the client (or any online visitor to the webpage) will be able to add markers and edit their attributes?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: your going to need a bit more detail, if your editing and you need users to input data your need a database backend and some security to restrict users. Openlayers would be an option for the front-end.